# O que são arquivos .phtml e quando eu devo usá-los?

Tags: php, phtml

Até pouco tempo atrás, nunca tinha ouvido falar em `phtml`, porém recentemente vejo que está sendo muito utilizado, principalmente por alguns frameworks (tais como Zend2).

Uma vez que posso pôr conteúdo html normalmente dentro de um arquivo `.php`, me pegunto qual a utilidade de se usar um arquivo `.phtml`?

Alguns pontos que gostaria de saber:

- Ele possui alguma vantagem de desempenho ou de interpretação?
- Quando devo optar pela extensão `.phtml`?
- Essa extensão foi criada para qual finalidade?

Comment: É interessante dizer também que arquivos phtml podem ser exibidos sem um servidor web, óbvio que o php em si não será renderizado, mas o html pode ser visto, facilitando assim alterações no código em qualquer ambiente.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Normalmente não se tem diferença de um tipo de arquivo para outro no que tange a renderização da página. É mais uma *commodity* para programadores quando projeto cresce

Normalmente:

- Arquivos .PHP não contém nada referente à View (HTML, JS, CSS...)
- Arquivos .PHTML contém a lógica mínima necessária, se houver, para renderizar e exibir aquilo que vêm das Models pelos Controllers.

A extensão **.phtml** em si era a extensão padrão de arquivos nos programas criados nos idos do PHP 2. A extensão **.php3** tomou seu lugar no PHP 3 e quando o PHP 4 chegou a extensão foi universalizada como **.php**, apesar de existir e ser usada por certo tempo a **.php4**.

Hoje em dia as extensões antigas ainda podem ser vistas em uso, afinal basta configurar a relação entre extensão e *Content-type* pelo servidor que qualquer coisa pode rodar como sendo um programa PHP. Mas isso é bem raro.

> [Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11859015/what-is-phtml-and-when-should-i-use-a-phtml-extension-rather-than-php)

Comment: Se minha resposta (atualmente a única) solucionou seu "problema" (que pra mim pareceu mais uma curiosidade), marque-a como resolvida. Sua dúvida hoje pode ser a de outra pessoa amanhã. ;)