# Coloquei a extensão do arquivo como .phtml e somente no chrome está exibindo todo o código. Por que?

Tags: php, html

Coloquei a extensão do arquivo como `.phtml` e somente no Google Chrome está exibindo todo o código da página, porém nos outros navegadores está interpretando normalmente.

A página é carregada dentro de um `iframe`. Se eu altero a extensão para `.php`, funciona.

Alguém sabe me dizer o por quê isso ocorre somente no chrome?

Comment: Está usando o zend framework?

Comment: Não está utilizando framework.

Comment: Dê mais detalhes do que está tentando fazer, da forma como está são muitas possibilidades.

Comment: Por que está usando `phtml`?

Comment: Está usando Apache? Está usando alguma library de preprocessamento de template? Está usando Zend? Porque está usando PHTML?

Comment: Quando pegamos o projeto as páginas já estavam com essa extenção phtml. Não sei porque utilizaram.

Comment: Talvez isso ajude a responder a pergunta [O que são arquivos .phtml e quando eu devo usa-los?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42971/o-que-s%C3%A3o-arquivos-phtml-e-quando-eu-devo-usá-los)

Comment: @MiguelBatista está usando Apache? Você pode adicionar uma condição para eles serem interpretados como PHP.

Comment: O mais estranho é que ele disse que no Chrome não funciona, mas nos outros funcionam.

Comment: isso que é estranho porque já possui a configuração no apache para interpretar a extensão e o problema só ocorre no chrome. Vixi, Jesus!

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Migrar do PHP 5.2.9 para PHP 5.6.8](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60451/migrar-do-php-5-2-9-para-php-5-6-8)

Comment: Pode parecer besta, mas... Você está mesmo acessando a URL do web server, e não um file:///, certo?

Comment: Valeu @bfavaretto, a url estava correta. O problema foi resolvido valeu.

Comment: Foi a resposta abaixo que resolveu? Se não foi, poderia colocar sua própria resposta para ajudar outros com o mesmo problema? Obrigado!

Comment: A resposta abaixa não resolveu.

Answer (score 3):

Creio que na verdade não esteja funcionando em nenhum navegador, mas outros navegadores diferente do chrome devem estar fazendo download do arquivo ao invés de exibir ou devem estar interpretando como `text/html`, o que ignora as tags php fazendo pensar que são tags html, o chrome deve estar interpretando como `plain/text`.

Como eu respondi aqui:

- [Migrar do PHP 5.2.9 para PHP 5.6.8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/60452/3635)

Entenda que o **Apache**, **Ngnix** e outros servidores equivalentes não usam extensões padronizadas, na verdade é você quem customiza, você pode até mesmo inventar a própria extensão se assim desejar, por exemplo editando o `httpd.conf` no apache:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .miguel
```

Pronto, será possivel usar `.miguel` como extensão para executar arquivos php. Ainda poderá adicionar arquivos index com extensões customizadas por exemplo:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.html index.htm index.miguel
</IfModule>
```

Então para que `.phtml` e `.php` são coisas customizadas de qualquer forma e se deseja adicionar faça isso:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .phtml
```

E isso:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.html index.htm index.phtml
</IfModule>
```

> **Nota:** Mas note que nem todas hospedagens irão lhe permitir customizar as extensões e o melhor de fato é se manter na mais comum que é usar `.php` para tudo, ou talvez um `mod_rewrite` e não usar extensões

Comment: Já possui essa configuração no apache.

Comment: @MiguelBatista então se escrever isto em um .phtml `<?php echo 1 + 2; ?>` no Firefox ou IE ele está exibindo `3`? Note que editei o começo da resposta.

Comment: é isso mesmo. No IE não verifiquei.

Comment: @MiguelBatista uma nota, depois de alterar as configurações e adicionar tais extensões extras é necessário reiniciar o Apache completamente pois se não isto não terá efeito.